# uml class diagram - when should use usage, aggregation or association?

Tags: uml

I am brand new in UML desgin. Here, I have a question about it. Let us say I have two class, one is main caller class A, and it will new another class B. Should I use usage to represent the relationship between A and B (or aggregation)? Moreover, if a class C calls a method in another class D. What should I use? Association? or usage? Please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean with "it will new another class B"? Please use correct English.

Comment: Browsing through a good book might be very helpful. e.g. this one:  http://www.uml-diagrams.org/dependency.html and learning from examples could be also helpful, e.g. this list: http://www.uml-diagrams.org/index-examples.html

Answer (score 10):

**Dependency** is the most abstract among all relationships. Between 2 classes it only means that one is somehow "aware" ot another. Example: An object of a class A receives a reference to an object of the class B (during some method execution) and do something with it (like calling its method). 
**Usage** is a special type of dependency and means that class A uses class B.

**Association** is somehow stronger relationship than dependency. Example: A class a has a member (attribute) of class B and permanently holds this reference. The difference from the previous example is that this link is long-term, versus short-term link expressed through dependency.

**Agregation** and **compositions** are also associations, but stronger ones. Their semantics depends on the implementation language or context. 
Agregation is a non-exclusive relationship of the type Group-Member (several Members belog to the same group and can also belong to other groups). When Group is destroyd - Members are just unasigned from it and not destroyd.
Composition is exclusive and very strong relationship: Whole-part. Part is under total control of Whole - is practically part of it. Without the Whole, the Part does not exist, so when the whole is destroyed, the Part will die as well.

Answer (score 6):

In UML, a *Usage* is a special type of *Dependency* in which one model element (e.g. an operation in class C) requires another model element (e.g. an operation in class D) for its "full implementation or operation". Thus, there is a usage dependency of your class C on your class D, but no association.

I have explained how to use associations in design models in my tutorial [Managing Unidirectional Associations in a JavaScript Frontend Web App](https://web-engineering.info/tech/JsFrontendApp/unidirectional-association-tutorial.html).

Comment: this is probably a good answer but the link is expired, all details should be included in the answer